# Tomcat Full GC Issue

Tags: tomcat

My Application stops working and below line shown in server logs constantly : 
[Full GC 1989887K->1989887K(1989888K), 3.8619050 secs]

My Server configuration is as below :

```
server
-verbose:gc
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
-XX:NewSize=1048m
-XX:MaxNewSize=1048m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=8
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:GCTimeRatio=20
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
 OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
cygwin=false
darwin=false
os400=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
esac
```

I am using Java 1.7, Tomcat 8 and postgres as database

Kindly help as I need to restart server after every 2 hours to start application working again

Answer (score 0):

Change your PermSize and MaxPermSize to 512m and try again :) . You will find these values in setenv.bat file in bin directory. Adjustments have to be made according to your needs and memory constraints . Check this article out here 
https://dzone.com/articles/java-performance-tuning

Comment: Now after changing to 512m, Application is stopping after 5 hours

Comment: you'll have to adjust values according to your needs and memory constraints !

Comment: check the link in my updated answer to understand better !

Answer (score 0):

Use incremental gc to reduce pauses

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
```